# Where can I buy sawn logs for all the different plots in Hearthfire?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, skyrim-hearthfire

You can buy land / build houses in Dawnstar, Falkrath and Morthal.

At each house, there are sources for clay and stone, but where can you buy the sawn logs for each plot?

*I know only the source for Falkrath, which is Riverwood.*

Comment: Reload an old save?

Comment: The local burlesque?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The wood needed in the Hearthfire DLC is distinct from the wood you can obtain from any chopping block. You are looking for [Sawn Logs](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Sawn_Log#Sawn_Logs). These can be purchased from several log merchants in the game:

- Aeri - Anga's Mill in the Pale
- Bolund - The wood mill in Falkreath
- Gilfre - Mixwater Mill in Eastmarch
- Grosta - Heartwood Mill in the Rift
- Hert - Half-Moon Mill in Falkreath
- Hod - Wood mill in Riverwood
- Kharag gro-Shurkul - Solitude Sawmill in Haafingar
- Thonnir - Wood mill in Morthal

Some of these merchants will also allow you to chop lumber from free if you complete enough radiant quests to raise their disposition. Note that if you saw your own logs, the merchant must be nearby for you to actually receive the lumber.

Comment: Your steward will also buy wood for you once you assign one.

Answer (score 10):

There are only a few NPCs that will sell you Sawn Logs (these are different from Firewood). The [UESP](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Sawn_Log#Sawn_Logs) has a handy list:

[image]

It sounds like you may not be talking to [Hod](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Hod), but one of his employees (Faendal, perhaps?). If you can't find him, consider one of the other NPCs.

Comment: Thanks and when I see the option to cut it myself. Does it mean to use the sawmill to gather lumbers? I've been trying to cut those myself in Half-Moon Mill but I can't see where to get my lumbers freshly cut.

Comment: @Warface You may need to do a quest for the mill worker (or otherwise raise their disposition) and then ask them for permission. Doing the animation without asking for permission gets you nothing.

Comment: They make a reference to simply not being able to give away the lumber for free. Also, Hod is very very lazy I rarely if ever see him at the mill. For being there I would say go to Hert despite her eyes glowing oddly.

Answer (score 3):

It doesn't matter where you buy the materials, they will be available for all plots.

You can buy or make your own logs at mills, or buy them through your [steward](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Steward#Personal_Stewards) (as well as clay and stone).