# Where to buy lumber?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, skyrim-hearthfire

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where can I buy sawn logs for all the different plots in Hearthfire?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/86874/where-can-i-buy-sawn-logs-for-all-the-different-plots-in-hearthfire)

I need more logs to finish up my house and the quest tells me to buy lumber. I've traveled to Riverwood to speak with the guy working by the sawmill but there's no dialog about buying wood from him. I've tried to cut the logs myself at the sawmill and no luck there either.

How can I get logs or lumber?